# PHP mailer not working on live server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have a problem with my PHP mailer , PHP mailer working in my localhost but its not working on live server

Here is my mailer.php

```
 <?php require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"); // path to the PHPMailer class
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "user@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "pswd"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("user@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body = "Youy payment received";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'message not send';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message sent.';
}
?>
```

when i am running this on server its shows this error

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: What error message does this contain? `$mail->ErrorInfo;`

Comment: What do the log files say? Without that you dig in the dark...

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky it shows this error message `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.`

Comment: Are you sure at the 100% that your login username and password are correct? no special characters to escape, too? Moreover, are you sure the SMTP port 465 is actually opened?

Comment: @briosheje Yes i am sure my user name and password are correct and my password not contain any special characters

Comment: @briosheje How can I check port 465 is open or not?

Comment: @user2894216 if you're absolutely sure that you don't need to escape any characterer in your username and password, just try to change the port from 465 to 25 and check if this works! !!!IMPORTANT!!! check also that in your php.ini you have UNCOMMENTED this line: extension=php_openssl.dll if it's commented, then it just CAN'T work.

Comment: @briosheje thanks for the help i found it server smtp_port is 25

Comment: @user2894216 oh, nice, so it works? if it doesn't please try to check your php.ini file like above!

Answer (score 1):

Try and look for the line `$mail->IsSMTP();` telling the class to use SMTP and remove it or comment it as follows:

`//$mail->IsSMTP();`

that way it would work

Answer (score 0):

> > > @briosheje Yes i am sure my user name and password are correct and my password not contain any special characters –  user2894216

Probably, you've to set up your username as from field too

```
$mail->Username = "user2894216"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "pswd"; // SMTP password
$mail->From = "user2894216";
```

btw, for gmail ssl://smtp mail service doesn't necessary to write the domain. Only the user name